# Plot conditional on value of a variable

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, series, annotate

I'm trying to annotate a plot conditional on a value of a variable:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(vectors.word):
     if vectors['count']>=50:
     plt.annotate(txt, (yframe.x[i], yframe.y[i]), fontsize=20)
```

But I get a ValueError:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Any ideas what is wrong with my conditional statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `vectors` is a pandas.DataFrame,  you probably want this pattern:

```
from i, v in enumerate(vectors.itertuples()):
    if v.count>=50:
        ...
        ... v.word ...
```